# Flexslider determine middle image an add class

Tags: javascript, css, flexslider

I have successfully integrated flexslider into my web page.

My settings are:

```
{
    animation: "slide",
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 0,
    animationLoop: true,
    slideShow: true,
    move: 1
    // ...
}
```

My question is, is there a way to determine middle image from three images shown on one "page"?
I looked into code and saw that when there is only one image on page this image is getting `flexslider-active` class but nothing more.

Any advice?

Comment: What is a middle image?

Comment: When sliding through images in every moment i have 3 images shown. So the middle one from them

Comment: Why can you not identify it from `.flexslider-active` if it unique for every flexslider you have? Could we also have the complete code: a snippet/JSFiddle/CodePen would be much appreciated.